# How to achieve following style for horizontal rule with css

Tags: html, css

I know it is possible to style a `<hr>` element, however I don't know how to achieve following look:

[image]

it might be hard to see, basically it should look like (going in horizontal drection) 5px dark brown, light brown, 5px dark brown, also there is background in the image around hr to make it stand out more, it is not part of design. Is this achievable with css (if so how) or do I need to use graphics?

Comment: is using a border (i.e. border-bottom) a viable alternative to using an hr?

Comment: It is, but I can't imagine how border could be styled this way, I'm struggling to achieve this with hr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
<hr style="border:0;height:1px;background: #dfded9; border-right: 5px solid #b2b1ae;border-left: 5px solid #b2b1ae">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KvGKV/

Answer (score 1):

Use border-top and border-bottom.

```
<hr style="border-top: 1px solid #DEDDD9;border-bottom: 1px solid #DEDDD9;">
```

or

```
<hr style="border: 1px solid #DEDDD9;">
```

Comment: Hi it's not like that, I know Its hard to see from picture but basically it should look like (going in horizontal drection) 5px dark brown, light brown, 5px dark brown

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I follow your question but you might be able to use a gradient like so:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/89h77/)

Style the `hr` like so:

```
hr {
    height: 10px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(black, white);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, center top, center bottom, from(black), to(white));
}
```

Except replace black and white with the colors you want.